# Best way to handle with ThreadAbortException in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, time-out

I often face up with execution timeout issue when developing web parts.

Each time a code-behind method process large data that may take times, the `Thread was being aborted` error occurs.

Because in SharePoint Online environment, we cannot modify execution timeout setting. So what is the best way to handle with this issue?